# UILabel word wrapping at the number sign instead of before the sign

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UI Label with text that is wrapping too late. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Why is it wrapping after the + sign?

The hack is to insert a newline right before + sign, but that won't look good on different screen sizes.

Here's what I have set on the UILabel:

```
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: Insert a no break character after the Plus? In particular I’m thinking of the Zero-width joiner (U+200D).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @matt for the comment which helped me solve this. I also should mention that I'm setting attributedText on this UILabel, which is why the lineBreakMode probably didn't work.

I fixed this by setting the text like so:

```
"... +\u{200D}$50"
```

Basically I added a zero width joiner as @matt suggested `\u{200D}`

Comment: So this is now causing another issue where the + symbol right before `\u{200D}` is now bolded. Quite a pain just to get word wrapping functionality working.